# Clicking on code could hyperlink to the documentation for that code

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, code

It would be nice if when clicking on code it could hyperlink to the documentation for that code.

I.e. when I'm viewing this question: [Programmatically generate video or animated GIF in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python), clicking inside the code block in the answer on the line

```
from PIL import Image
```

could take me to [the official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html).

Can't they do that automatically? For all code?

Comment: And how would an algorithm figure out that `from pil import image` somehow implies a link towards a specific website ? How does it know that I didn't write my own module and mistakenly named it the same as the module available on pypy ? And for lesser known languages with less centralized module distribution?

Comment: Most code is such a hot mess that it would be unfeasible to try to make an algorithm guess even what lines are worth analysing in the first place, let alone where to look. It's a nice idea but impractical at best.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think such a feature would be really useful.

If you're going to use that snippet in your own code, you need to copy/paste the code into your IDE and your IDE will be able to provide the documentation.

If you want to test/analyze code in a *question* to help solving the author's problem, you'll copy/paste the code into your IDE and your IDE will be able to provide the documentation. If you're proficient enough with a language/framework/API to not need an IDE, you're probably familiar enough with it not to need this feature at all.

Stack Exchange won't be able to provide the 'correct' documentation link; even though with the help of tags/syntax highlighting hints the system may be able to derive *some* information about the code being used, things like versions of the language/library/API etc. will still be unknown.

Comment: I think the lack of feasability is a much bigger problem than whether it's useful or not.

Comment: Some of the domain specific sites have had feature requests for this.  On the site that I mod, people frequently link to the API doc in both questions and answers (o they get edited in) to the point where it is almost standard practice. So, globally I think this would be bad/infeasible, but on some sites it would be very valuable (and potentially feasible).